# Can a genie use its Plane Shift ability on unwilling creatures?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, planes, targeting

A [Genie](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/genie.htm) has the SP ability of a limited plane shift.

> A genie can enter any of the elemental planes, the Astral Plane, or the Material Plane. This ability transports the genie and up to eight other creatures, provided they all link hands with the genie. It is otherwise similar to the spell of the same name (caster level 13th).

The Plane Shift spell has two versions.

One targets a creature touched, the other several hand-held, willing creatures.

Can the Genie use its Plane Shift on an unwilling creature, or is it limited to the willing version (seeing as it mentions 'itself and others', per the willing-group version)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Link hands" does not suggest an aggressive action.

If the special ability is "otherwise similar" after describing exactly who can Plane Shift, then it is limited to voluntary travelers.

Comment: The counter-arguement would be that 'link hands' could be done in a pin. I'm leaning your way, but if I can eliminate that argument too, that's gonna be even better.

Comment: I guess it could be a counter argument, but the word is never ever used that way.